# Get cell value from Excel file based on the column name in JAVA

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am trying to read an Excel file and get the value of a particular column.

I used  `row.getCell(0),toString()` to get the first column value. Instead of using the column index, I wanted to use the Column Name. How can I do this ? `getCell` allows only the index to be entered. how can I pass the column name. Something like `row.getCell(COLUMN_NAME)`

Comment: which Java excel apis are you utilizing?

Comment: Check `org.apache.poi.hssf.util.CellReference`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are utilizing `apache-poi` for your purpose. You can use a util class `CellReference`, sample usage below:

```
XSSFSheet ws = wb.getSheet("Sheet1");
CellReference cellReference = new CellReference("A11");
XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(cellReference.getRow());
if (row != null) {
    XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(cellReference.getCol());
}
```

Comment: Hi. I cannot use the cell reference A11. I just know the row index and the column name. using these 2 inputs, i have to retrieve the cell value.

Comment: If you are referring to the 'values' in the first row as Column Names, then you would have to iterate over the values of the first row

Comment: ya got it. Thanks for the hint :)